# gitlab API gitlab4j Java change default branche

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm using `gitlab4j`to change project default branch from `master` to `dev` with Java, I have authenticated changed the default branch but changes not saved

```java
GitLabApi gitLabApi = new GitLabApi("***", "mytoken");
List<Project> projects = gitLabApi.getProjectApi().getProjects();

for (Project project : projects) {
    if(project.getId()==633) {
        project.setDefaultBranch("dev");            
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i Hvae resolved this problem by adding :

gitLabApi.getProjectApi().updateProject(project);

so the new code is  :

for (Project project : projects) {

```
        if(project.getId()==633) {
            project.setDefaultBranch("dev");
            gitLabApi.getProjectApi().updateProject(project);

        }

    }
```